# How to access Python web.py server in LAN?

Tags: python, python-2.7, network-programming, web.py

So, I created a simple site written in Python using Web.py. It's now live and running. I can access it through my computer that runs the server by typing one of this: `http://0.0.0.0:8080/` or `http://localhost:8080/`. However, I can only access it through that computer that runs the Python Web.py server.

I tried accessing it with another computer on the same network, but it gives me an error. Help?

Comment: Which address did you type on other computers from the same network?

Comment: @enedil I tried the server's IP with port and also the other pc IP's with the same port but still can't access the site.

Comment: Maybe check firewall rules?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your firewall. Try to disable it and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Disable your firewall:

```
sudo ufw allow 8080
```

If it still doesn't work replace

```
0.0.0.0
```

With your IP address on the LAN.